# I have to calculate the trend of obesity rate for each county in US from 2004 to 2013. How do I run this regression in R?

Tags: r, time-series, linear-regression

I know how to run a linear regression model in R, but my problem is that I can't figure out how to find the trend for each county. My data is in the form of "name of each county", "obesity rate for year 1", "obesity rate for year 2"... "obesity rate year 10". I want to find out the average change in obesity rate per county

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you right I would do this linear regression:
 *Obesity rate = a + b * Country + e*

```
lm(ObesityRate = factor(Country), data = df)
```

- The intercept can be interpreted as the overall change of obesity
  when you set all the country dummy variables to 0 (e.g. 4%). So the
  "world-specific" change in obesity is 4%.
- The coefficients are the change in obesity explained by the countries (e.g. 3% for country A). 
  Therefore, the "country-specific" change in obesity would be 7%.

If it's not clear what I meant please let me know.